# SQL Advance ORDER By

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
x----------y------z
a------ 2014---28
a------ 2013---26
b------ 2014---38
b------ 2013---25
c------ 2013---18
c------ 2014---17
```

and need it to look like this:

```
x----------y------z
b------ 2014---38
b------ 2013---25
a------ 2014---28
a------ 2013---26
c------ 2014---17
c------ 2013---18
```

So I need to sort based on Z high to low, but I need last years date immediately below it. I can can get close but not close enough please help!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.* from mytable t1
join (
    select max(z) max_z, x
    from mytable
    group by x
) t2 on t2.x = t1.x
order by t2.max_z desc, t1.x, t1.z desc, t1.y desc
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, I had the right right idea just made it messy I actually got it to work by creating a temp table, but this is much much cleaner thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If analytic functions available:

```
select x,y,z from 
    (
        select t1.*
        ,max(z) over (partition by x) mz 
        from mytable t1
    ) 
order by mz desc, x,z desc, y desc
```